# NSDateFormatter iOS9

Tags: swift, ios9, nsdateformatter

This was working fine before the iOS9update, why is it crashing and saying it unwrapped an optional value finding nil? It won't let me change date! to date? either. Thanks

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = event?.eventDate
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)

cell.eventDateLabel.text = dateString
```

Comment: `if let date = event?.eventDate as? NSDate { ... }` ?

Comment: Now I get this error... Downcast from 'NSDate?' to 'NSDate' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Comment: BTW, if doing this repeatedly (e.g. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), don't instantiate a new `NSDateFormatter` for every cell. Instantiate one (e.g. a class property), and then reuse that. Date formatters are notoriously expensive, so you don't want to be instantiating them repeatedly if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to check whether the event exists like this:

```
var dateString = ""
if let good = event {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(good.eventDate)
}
cell.eventDateLabel.text = dateString
```

Depending on the structure of the event type, you may also need to check that eventDate is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
if let date = event?.eventDate {
    cell.eventDateLabel.text = date.formatted
}
```

You will need to add this extension:

```
extension NSDate {
    struct Date {
        static let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    } 
    var formatted: String {
        Date.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return Date.formatter.stringFromDate(date)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Echizzle http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work